# wordpress website admin panel is showing index of page

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-admin

I have wordpress website & I am trying to open the wp-admin using url: https://<website_name>/wp-admin.
Whenever I login i shows me index of page.

Index of /wp-admin/[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fwk3.png)

Please help

I was expecting to wp-admin console

Comment: Can you see a thin gray line at the top of the site with wp panel keys ?

Comment: There is no `index.php` shown in that file list, which explains why you get the directory listing instead. By default this folder should of course contain one, as you can see f.e. in the repository here, https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/master/wp-admin So go get the appropriate version of that file, for the WP version you are using. (And maybe figure out how you "lost" it in the first place - perhaps just an oversight when uploading the site, but could also be that other files are missing elsewhere. Might make sense to re-upload the whole thing ...)